# T-sql Adding same amount to range of chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL SERVER database with a primary key (`compid`) which is a char but looks like a numbered ID . we have 20,000 computers in our DB each having it's own 8 digit code (`compid`)

eg. my computer is `28154326`. This is in a char field.

I have numbered 50 computers incorrectly and instead of `28184000 - 28184050` I have put `28154000 - 28154050`.

Is there any way I can change this range of computers to have the correct compid without going through each one by one?

These are in the `compconfig` table so to extract them it would be

```
select * from compconfig (nolock)
```

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL? Retag your question to get better answers

Comment: SQL SERVER ADDED. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this query solver your issue?

```
UPDATE compconfig 
SET compid=CAST(compid AS INT)+30000
WHERE CAST(compid AS INT) BETWEEN 28154000 AND 28154050
```

Please select and confirm before updating.

Comment: Yup, that was pretty much the answer I was writing :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, supposing it's a once-off fix you're trying to run:

```
UPDATE compconfig
SET compid = REPLACE(compid, '2815', '2818')
WHERE compid BETWEEN '28154000' AND '28154050'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE as 
(
select compid,28184000+ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) rn from compconfig where CAST(compid AS INT) BETWEEN 28154000 AND 28154050
)

UPDATE CTE SET compid = rn
```